# Where am I going wrong in this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

where am I going wrong in this integral?

$$\int\frac{xe^x}{(x+1)^2}dx$$

[image]

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/IkDOi image link

Comment: It's hard to say, since you aren't showing anything where you may have gone either right or wrong.

Comment: mathguy, image link is in the first comment.

Comment: We shouldn't have to click on a link.

Comment: Can not add image.

Comment: You can add Mathjax though

Comment: Wait... is that supposed to be $e^x$ instead of $e^2$?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.

Answer (score 3):

$f=xe^x$ and $g'=\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$ so that you get $\frac{e^x+xe^x}{1+x}$ behind the integral sign. Numerator is factorable and simplifies that fraction considerably.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @J.Jay0192 Hi, I did not downvote. It is just that it is better to type up the problem instead of inserting a link. Spend some time on formatting and you can LEARN a lot from this site (Just like me...)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm new here. Tips like yours are valuable. :)

Comment: Did you perhaps mean $g'=1/(1+x)^2$?

Comment: @mickep. Yes, edited, thanks